# Recursive method output

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone please tell me the output of this code? My understanding is, once the stack completes execution, display() method will start displaying 1,2,3,4,5, but it displays 0,1,2,3,4 can some explain how that happens?

```
package com.test.examples.datastructures.examples.recursive;

public class Recursive {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int var = 5;
        recursive(var);
    }

    public static void recursive(int i) {
        System.out.println("i " +i);
        if (i<1) {
            return;
        }
        recursive(i=i-1);
        display(i);
    }

    public static void display(int i) {
        System.out.println(" " +i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Java environment right now, but I don't see how you could get either output.  You are println-ing `i` twice, once directly in recursive and once in display.

Comment: Here is the output : <br/>
i 5
i 4
i 3
i 2
i 1
i 0

 0
 1
 2
 3
 4

Comment: If you show code, you should generaly tag the language of that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display()` is not going to display anything until recursion reaches its end.  At that point, `i<1`, which translates to i is 0.  So the last recursive call returns and the next statement will be the display, the first time done.  It prints 0.  Then it returns from `recursive()`, and the next line is display (1), and so on.

Comment: My understanding it stack create a local copy , after the recursion complete the stack should have 5,4,3,2,1 AND that the order display should print value of i. How come it's display the value in the incremental order rather then in the decremental order this what i don't understand

Comment: @user3593068, the code starts with 5 and decrements.  You're right, those are on the stack, in that order 5,4,3,2,1.  The first `display()` call is after the final decrement -- display gets `0`.  Then the returns are popping values off the stack, in the reverse order they were put on there.

Comment: I still don't understand, When recursion was called for 5 didn't display(5) will be place on the stack and same for the other values of i. I guess I am still missing some thing important

Comment: @user3593068, When `main()` called `recursive()` with `5`, `5` went on the stack (with return address we'll ignore).  `recursive()` decrements `5` (`i`).  `display()` won't see any action until `recursive()` finishes calling `recursive()`.  I do realize this is hard.  It's hard the first few times, but when recursion "clicks", it suddenly seems so simple and elegant.  Hang in there.

Comment: FWIW, if you can set a breakpoint on the `return` statement inside `recursive` and run to there and stop, that will really help you gain insight as you examine the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The method `display` never gets called with the value 5 because the preceding line subtracts one from the value in i:

```
    recursive(i=i-1);
    display(i);
```

The value passed into the next call to recursive is the value of i *after* it is decremented by one. First the expression i - 1 is evaluated, then the assignment to i happens, then the value stored in i by the assignment is passed to the recursive call. If you change this to

```
    recursive(i-1);
    display(i);
```

then the display method calls will print out 1 through 5. Try to avoid mutating variables in recursive functions, it's usually unneeded and only causes confusion (and changing argument values is considered by many people to be bad style anyway). You could put `final` on the argument i in the method signature of the recursive method, and it will prevent changing the value in i:

```
public class Recursive {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int var = 5;
        recursive(var);
    }

    public static void recursive(final int i) {
        System.out.println("i " +i);
        if (i<1) {
            return;
        }
        recursive(i-1);
        display(i);
    }

    public static void display(int i) {
        System.out.println(" " +i);
    }
}
```

Also having a recursive method that relies solely on side-effects for output is strange, you could do this instead:

```
import java.util.*;

public class R {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(r(5));
    }

    public static List r(final int i) {
        if (i < 1) return new ArrayList();
        List list = r(i - 1);
        list.add(i);
        return list;
    }
}
```